# Java character based queue using an array

Tags: java, arrays, char, stack

Below is a code for a character based queue using an array. Currently, I'm able to push characters into the array but I get some random numbers when returning once I check the index. What needs to be changed here in order to see a pushed character? For example "Array Deque : 97" returns 97 instead of the a.

------------output---------------
  Array Deque Operations

1. add
2. get
3. set
4. remove
5. check empty
6. clear
7. size

   1

Enter index and element

0

a

Array Deque : 97

Do you want to continue (Type y or n)

---

```
import java.util.Scanner;
class ArrayDeque
{
private int[] a;
private int j, n;
public ArrayDeque()
{
j = 0;
n = 0;
resize();
}

public boolean isEmpty()
{
return n == 0;
}

public void clear()
{
j = 0;
n = 0;
resize();
}
public int getSize()
{
return n;
}
private void resize()
{
int[] temp = new int[Math.max(2 * n, 1)];
for (int k = 0; k < n; k++)
temp[k] = a[(j + k) % a.length];
a = temp;
j = 0;
}
public int get(int i)
{
return a[(j + i) % a.length];
}

public int set(int i, int x)
{
int y = a[(j + i) % a.length];
a[(j + i) % a.length] = x;
return y; 
}

void add(int i, int x)
{
if (n + 1 > a.length)
resize();
if (i < n/2)
{
j = (j == 0) ? a.length - 1 : j - 1;

for (int k = 0; k <= i - 1; k++)
a[(j + k) % a.length] = a[(j + k + 1)%a.length];
}
else
{
for (int k = n; k > i; k--)
a[(j + k) % a.length] = a[(j + k - 1)%a.length];
}
a[(j + i) % a.length] = x;
n++;
}

public int remove(int i)
{
int x = a[(j + i) % a.length];
if (i < n/2)
{

for (int k = i; k > 0; k--)
a[(j + k) % a.length] = a[(j + k - 1) % a.length];

j = (j + 1) % a.length;
}
else
{
for (int k = i; k < n - 1; k++)
a[(j + k) % a.length] = a[(j + k + 1) % a.length];
}
n--;
if (3 * n < a.length)
resize();
return x;
}

public void display()
{
System.out.print("\nArray Deque : ");
int p = j;
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
System.out.print(a[p % a.length] +" ");
p++;
}
System.out.println();
}
}

public class ArrayDequeTest
{
public static void main(String[] args)
{
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Array Deque Test\n");

ArrayDeque ad = new ArrayDeque();

char ch;
do
{
System.out.println("\nArray Deque Operations\n");
System.out.println("1. add");
System.out.println("2. get");
System.out.println("3. set");
System.out.println("4. remove");
System.out.println("5. check empty");
System.out.println("6. clear");
System.out.println("7. size");

int choice = scan.nextInt();
switch (choice)
{
case 1 :
System.out.println("Enter index and element");
ad.add(scan.nextInt(), scan.next().charAt(0) );   
break;
case 2 :
System.out.println("Enter index");
System.out.println("Result : "+ ad.get(scan.nextInt() ));
break;
case 3 :
System.out.println("Enter index and element");
ad.set(scan.nextInt(), scan.nextInt() );
break;
case 4 :
System.out.println("\nEnter index");
ad.remove(scan.nextInt() );
break;
case 5 :
System.out.println("\nEmpty Status : "+ ad.isEmpty());
break;
case 6 :
System.out.println("\nArray Deque Cleared");
ad.clear();
break;
case 7 :
System.out.println("\nSize = "+ ad.getSize() );
break;   
default :
System.out.println("Wrong Entry \n ");
break;   
}
ad.display();   

System.out.println("\nDo you want to continue (Type y or n) \n");
ch = scan.next().charAt(0);
} while (ch == 'Y'|| ch == 'y');
}
}
```

Comment: How to make this part that returns an integer to return a char instead?

case 2 :
System.out.println("Enter index");
System.out.println("Result : "+ ad.get(scan.nextInt() ));

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting the correct result, just in the ASCII format. As seen [here](http://www.asciitable.com/), the decimal value for character `a` is 97.

To obtain `a`, simply cast your result to `char`:

```
char letter = (char) a[p % a.length];
System.out.print(letter);
```

Comment: Oh, I see. Is there a quick way to translate it back to the a?

Comment: You can use `chr` function for that

Comment: @David Just cast it to a `char`: `System.out.print(((char) a[p % a.length]) +" ")`

Comment: @David You also don't need the `+" "`, as `PrintStream#print` has overloads for all primitives, as well as `Object` for reference types. `System.out.print((char) a[p % a.length]);`

Comment: Would you happen to know how to do the same for the "Case 2" so that it prints an actual char instead of an ASCII?

Comment: It should work the same way, just pass the ASCII as an argument to `chr` function, then it will return the actual char

Comment: @Andreas any chance you could provide a code that needs to be replaced/added?

Comment: It should be something like this `System.out.println("Result : "+ chr(ad.get(scan.nextInt() )));`